# Will a class that is declared within a member initializer of a constructor of another class be visible outside it?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Consider the following piece of code:

```
struct Foo { 
    void* p; 
    Foo() : p{(class Bar*)0} {}
};

Bar* bar;
```

The latest versions of GCC (8.2) and Clang (7.0.0) fail to compile it. So does ICC (19.0.1).
However MSVC (v19.16) compiles it cleanly.

The error from GCC is:  `error: 'Bar' does not name a type; did you mean 'char'?`
Clang and ICC issue similar messages.

Conformance viewer for [all four compilers at godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/4-KPiG).

So which of the compiler(s) is correct as per the standard?

Comment: `did you mean 'char'?`: gcc sound like early '00s google :D

Comment: @YSC: Yeah. Thought so too. That's why I posted the error from GCC. Other compilers had bland error messages. :)

Comment: I believe that MSVC is correct, and Richard Smith seems to agree. (From https://zygoloid.github.io/cppcontest2018.html, section The Most Surprising: 'GCC, Clang, and ICC all get this "wrong", but MSVC follows the spec.')

Comment: @cpplearner: Can you please post an answer deriving this conclusion from the standard?

Comment: @P.W My understanding is largely the same as eerorika's: 1. The identifier is "declared in the smallest namespace or block scope that contains the declaration." 2. Since block scope is the production of compound statement ([\[stmt.block\]](http://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.block#1.sentence-2)), and the mem-initializer-list appears outside any compound statement, the "smallest namespace or block scope" can only be the global namespace scope.

Comment: @cpplearner that's it, that's where I saw it!

Comment: I really want to know why this was close-voted for "unclear problem statement"...

Comment: @Quentin - I could easily see downvoting this question for promulgating evil. There's already more than enough evil in the world.

Comment: @T.E.D. then you've come to the wrong language ;)

Comment: @Quentin - You ain't lyin.

Answer (score 13):

> - [basic.lookup.elab] ... If the elaborated-type-specifier is introduced by
>     the class-key and this lookup does not find a previously declared type-name ... the elaborated-type-specifier is a declaration that introduces the class-name as described in [basic.scope.pdecl]
> - [basic.scope.pdecl] - for an elaborated-type-specifier of the form
>
>   class-key identifier
>
>   if the elaborated-type-specifier is used in the decl-specifier-seq or parameter-declaration-clause of a
>     function defined in namespace scope *[does not apply because of scope]*, ... otherwise, except as a friend declaration, the identifier is declared in the
>     smallest namespace or block scope that contains the declaration.

Now, the tricky bit. Is the member initialiser list *"contained"* in the scope of the constructor or not? If not, then the smallest block or namespace scope is the global namespace and the program would be well-formed. If yes, then the smallest scope is the block scope of the constructor, and thus the class would not be declared in the global scope.

As far as I can tell, there is no rule saying that mem-init-list is "contained in the block scope of the constructor". It is outside the curly brackets that delimit the scope. As such, the program is well-formed.

Mem-init-list *is* part of the constructor body [dcl.fct.def.general], but that body is neither a block scope nor a namespace scope, so it is not relevant to the rule in [basic.scope.pdecl].

Comment: I don't get how "name" and "evaluate" can mix: names are looked up and expression are evaluated, right?

Comment: @YSC Evaluations and declarations do seem orthogonal to me, but I include that rule because it's the only rule (besides one about where names are looked up from) about *scope* in the member init list that I could find. I could be wrong if I were to assume that the rule does not apply.

Comment: I don't think we could find a better matching rule, though I'm trying. It may be a wording issue.

Comment: BTW, I think you lack an answer to the question itself: is it legal?

Comment: @eerorika: The last para of your answer sums up my predicament too.

Comment: @YSC My answer is that it is not legal if mem-init-list is "in the block scope of the constructor". I haven't found a definitive rule that would say that it is, and in absence of such rule, the answer is that the example program *is* legal. But I've provided my best effort to show a rule that could be interpreted the case to be the opposite.

Comment: @eerorika *"[member init list] is outside the curly brackets that delimit the scope"* The constructor parameters are in the constructor scope, and they are visible in the member init list, so this makes me think that the member init list has to be at the same (or deeper) scope.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat But [function parameter scope](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.scope.param) is not block or namespace scope

Comment: @cpplearner Thanks, noted. Put my point still applies: If member init list can access parameters, then the scope it's contained in has to be equal or included into the parameter scope.

Comment: @eerorika "[member init list] is outside the curly brackets that delimit the scope"
What about the fact that function-try-block for constructors have the `try` part before the `:` preceding the init list ?

Comment: @REMqb What about it? As discussed in earlier comments, the function parameter scope is greater than the block scope of the function definition. In case of a function-try-block, the (potential) function parameter scope ends at the end of the last associated handler

Comment: @eerorika In [dcl.fct.def.general] we can see that the _ctor-initializer_ is considered part of function-body. Also a bit lower there is an example of the function-local predefined variable `__func__` being used in the init list but that it can't be used to default init the function parameters.

Comment: @REMqb OK. What is your conclusion based on that?

Comment: The _ctor-initializer_ is part of the constructor's _function-body_ ([dcl.fct.def.general]) but **not** its _compound-statement_ that defines a block scope ([stmt.block]), so I think the declaration does not have block scope.

Answer (score 8):

This is about declaration rules and scope rules; (*elaborated type specifier* may also declare a *class-name* in an expression).

> [scope.declarative/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic#scope.declarative-3):
>   The names declared by a declaration are introduced into the scope in
>   which the declaration occurs, except that the presence of a friend
>   specifier, certain uses of the elaborated-type-specifier
>   ([dcl.type.elab]), and using-directives ([namespace.udir]) alter this
>   general behavior.

a constructor has a scope (as [eeroika's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54650179/1621391) mentions), likewise anything *declared* therein. That is why this should be valid

```
struct Foo { 
    void* p; 
    Foo() : p{(class Bar*)0} {
        Bar* bar;
    }
};
```

https://godbolt.org/z/m3Tdle

But not:

```
struct Foo { 
    void* p; 
    Foo() : p{(class Bar*)0} {
        //Scope of Bar only exists here
    }
};

Bar* bar;
```

**EDIT:**
More details about this:

The so-called "forward declaration" in C++ is technically one of multiple "forms" of [*`elaborated-type-specifier`*](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.elab#nt:elaborated-type-specifier); And [*only two*](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.scope#pdecl-7) forms may introduce a name. (Emphasis mine)

> The point of declaration of a class first declared in an
>   *elaborated-type-specifier* is as follows:
>
> - (7.1) for a declaration of the *form*
>
>   *class-key attribute-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub>  identifier;* **`//<-- Note the semi colon`**
>
>   the identifier is declared to be a *class-name* in the scope that contains
>     the declaration, otherwise
> - (7.2) for an elaborated-type-specifier of the *form*
>
>   *class-key identifier*
>
>   if the *elaborated-type-specifier* is used in the *decl-specifier-seq* or *parameter-declaration-clause* of a function defined in namespace scope, the *identifier* is declared as a *class-name* in the **namespace** that contains the declaration; otherwise, except as a friend declaration, the identifier is declared in the smallest namespace or **block scope** that contains the declaration. [ *Note:* These rules also apply within templates. —- *end note* ] **[ *Note:*
>     Other *forms* of elaborated-type-specifier do not declare a new name,
>     and therefore must refer to an existing type-name.** See
>     [basic.lookup.elab] and [dcl.type.elab]. —- *end note* ]

---

Here's another interesting bit about it;

> [dcl.type.elab/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.elab#1) An
>   *attribute-specifier-seq* shall not appear in an *elaborated-type-specifier* unless the latter is the sole constituent of
>   a declaration...

That is why this (below) is valid, See it here *https://godbolt.org/z/IkmvGn*;

```
void foo(){
    void* n = (class Boo*)(0);
    Boo* b;
}

class [[deprecated("WTF")]] Mew;
```

But this, (below) is incorrect<sup>1</sup>; See it here *https://godbolt.org/z/8X1QKq*;

```
void foo(){
    void* n = (class [[deprecated("WTF")]] Boo*)(0);
}

class [[deprecated("WTF")]] Mew;
```

- <sup>1</sup>Strangely, GCC accepts it, but gives this warning:

  ```
  attributes ignored on elaborated-type-specifier that is not a forward declaration [-Wattributes]
  ```

---

To see all the other "forms" of *`elaborated-type-specifier`* see [dcl.type.elab](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.elab)

---

**Edit 2**

To double-check my understanding, I asked further, and [@Simon Brand made me realise some edge cases](https://twitter.com/TartanLlama/status/1095954113463009280), and that is partly hinted by [basic.scope/declarative-4.note-2](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.scope#declarative-4.note-2). But chiefly by the second quote in this answer [basic.scope/pdecl-7.2](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.scope#pdecl-7.2)

An *elaborated-type-specifier* within a *function-parameter-scope* will leak its class-name to the enclosing namespace (note: this is not *class-scope*).

This is valid *https://godbolt.org/z/Fx5B83*:

```
struct Foo { 
    static void foo(void* = (class Bat*)0); //Leaks it past class-scope
};

void moo(){
    Bat* m;
}
```

Even if you hide it in nested classes *https://godbolt.org/z/40Raup*:

```
struct Foo { 
    class Moo{
        class Mew{ 
            void foo(void* = (class Bat*)0); //
        };
    };
};

void moo(){
    Bat* m;
}
```

... However, the name stops leaking at the closest `namespace` *https://godbolt.org/z/YDljDo* .

```
namespace zoo {
    struct Foo { 
        class Moo{
            class Mew{ 
                void foo(void* = (class Bat*)0);
            };
        };
    };
}
void moo(){
    zoo::Bat* m;
}
```

***Finally,***

*mem-init-list* is a *compound-statement* and does not have a *function-parameter-scope*; So, if you want to achieve, the leakage, do the declaration in the *function-parameter-scope*. See *https://godbolt.org/z/CqejYS*

```
struct Foo { 
    void* p; 
    Foo(void* = (class Zoo*)(0)) 
        : p{(class Bar*)0} {
        Bar* bar;
    }
};

Zoo* m;     //Zoo* leaked
//Bar* n    //Bar* did not leak
```

Comment: But saying `class Bar` should implicitly forward declare it, no? Even there?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, If I am not mistaken, the so-called "forward declaration" is actually one of multiple forms of [`elaborated-type-specifier`](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.elab#nt:elaborated-type-specifier); And only [two forms introduce a name](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.scope#pdecl-7). I'm not sure I understand your comment correctly though....

Comment: Nope, you understood correctly, and also (it seems) answered correctly - thanks :)

Comment: (Would you consider adding that to the answer? I think it's the key)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, Thanks for the suggestion, done... improved the answer a bit :-)

Comment: Nice one pal .

Comment: @WhiZTiM: Thank your for your detailed answer with references. So your conclusion is the opposite of eerorika's, that MSVC is wrong and the other compilers are correct?

Comment: @P.W, yes,  I asked further, and I've edited my answer to include that. Generally, *mem-init-list* does not have the same scope as in *function-parameter-list*. Please see my second edit.

Comment: @WhiZTiM: In your last example `Bar` **also** leaked. Compilation failed for MSVC because of the missing semi-colon. See: https://godbolt.org/z/9IJ3Fd

Comment: @P.W, Yes, my point exactly, MSVC leaks names in `mem-init-list`.. and that is not standard's compliant AFAICT.